# Reading from XML file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm building a game in javascript / html5 that is essentially a maze with locked doors. I want to use an XML file to keep track of the doors that are locked (as the player will have the opportunity to lock doors themselves) but I've never used XML files before and everything I've read about them I'm finding confusing.

My XML file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <doors>
    <1>
        <left>unlocked</left>
        <right>unlocked</right>
        <bottom>locked</bottom>
    </1>
    <2>
        <left>unlocked</left>
        <right>unlocked</right>
        <bottom>unlocked</bottom>
    </2>
    <3>
        <right>unlocked</right>
        <bottom>unlocked</bottom>
        <top>unlocked</top>
    </3>
    <4>
        <left>unlocked</left>
        <right>unlocked</right>
        <top>unlocked</top>
    </4>
    </doors>
```

I've written code that tests for collision with the doors but I want it to do something like this:

```
if (player.x < bottomDoor.x + bottomDoor.width  && 
     player.x + player.width  > bottomDoor.x &&
     player.y < bottomDoor.y + bottomDoor.height && 
     player.y + player.height > bottomDoor.y) {
        if(*bottom door locked read from XML file*)
                 *popup "door is locked"*
            else
            window.location = ( "nextRoom.html?p1=");
    }
```

where * indicates sudocode.

I just need to know how to read the data for room 1, bottom door, or potentially how to read for each door in the room and parse the string to test for it where needed. If anyone could explain this to me I'd appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Your XML looks like a pretty bad modeling of the problem. What about: `<doors><door locked="bottom" /><door locked="" /><door locked="" /><door locked="" /></doors>` instead? Also, if you're using JavaScript you might prefer using JSON instead of XML as it uses similar notation to JS object literals.

Comment: If I got that right, then both, the javascript and the XML file, reside on the player's computer? If so, there is an even bigger problem you have to solve first: you cannot read any local files with javascript in most browsers, for security reasons. You can only get content from webservers using XMLHttpRequest.